# Android SQLite how to change autoincrement primary key?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I want add new `column` in my table and set it `column` as **AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY**, but I already have in this table `AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY`.

It is possible?

Comment: No, it is not possible. If you have an AUTOINCREMENT PRIMARY KEY in your table then you can't use again this in that table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't alter columns in SQLite.

[have a look at the things Sqlite does not implement](http://www.sqlite.org/omitted.html)

You should drop the table and create a new one and copy the data back

Answer (score 1):

Courtesy goes to **[SQLite - AUTO INCREMENT](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_using_autoincrement.htm)**

> SQLite AUTOINCREMENT is a keyword used for auto incrementing a value
>   of a field in the table. We can auto increment a field value by using
>   AUTOINCREMENT keyword when creating a table with specific column name
>   to auto incrementing it.

So for your requirement , you can't use again this on run time  .
Only One way

1. **Uninstall App & create once again** .